# xamarin, cross platform sound api to play streams

Tags: api, audio, xamarin, cross-platform

i wounder if anyone knows some crossPlatform audio api. I need to play a stream hosted in a webservice. I try Plugin.MediaManager but i think it is impossible to play the stream with that api.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think there is a package for that yet.

Altough you could fix it yourself. Just use a depedency service for each platform.

This is a helpful link perhaps: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42008/audio-streaming-on-ios-and-android